# How to retrieve children and grand children of a node in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL DB with the 2 following tables:

**Node**: `id` (this is just for the example, in reality there are more fields).

**Edge**: `source`. `target` which are ids of 2 nodes and `weight` which represents the connection strength.

I'd like to get for a certain node id his 20 top children by connection strength and for each one of his children their respective top 20 children (Meaning a maximum of 400 node rows total).

I have looked into the matter and I understand the most becoming way is probably with recursive procedures (as functions cannot be called recursively in MySQL) but seeing as MySQL does not support table variables I had to look for something else which brought up temp tables.

After all that I am still lost on how on earth am I going to this, would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Could you precise: is it a oneshot or would you like to do it frequently? ... ? The goal of my question is to decide if I try to give a simple solution or if optimization is really needed.

Comment: If you are only (always) going two levels deep you could probably self-join twice. Otherwise you might want to look at something like neo4j.

Comment: @farvilain, This is a part of an application for some website so the frequency is dependent on a lot of things. basically a user enters an id and then the query has to run. 

ethrbunny, i have tried it with self join which works fine when the top 20 selection isn't needed but i couldn't figure out what to do when the problem is as described above. Also, I would like to stay with MySQL if possible.

Comment: I have a solution but using concatenation... enjoy Oo

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets try.

First, just the first level

```
select e.target, e.weight
from Edge e
where e.source=:id
order by e.weight limit 20;
```

Trying to write a subquery in select, cause if I make a join, I'm not capable to limit correctly on 20 **for each** e.target :(

```
select e.target, e.weight, (select group_concat( f.target separator ',')
    from edge f
    where f.source = e.target
    order by f.weight limit 20;
)
from edge e
where e.source=2
order by e.weight limit 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write 2 queries for that..

First Query would be..

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS 
SELECT 
eChild.* 
FROM 
Edge eParent
INNER JOIN
Edge eChild
ON ( eParent.target = eChild.source )
WHERE eParent.source = <X>
ORDER BY eParent.weight DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Now, second query needs to be executed for each of the results in the temp_table..

```
SELECT 
eChild.* 
FROM 
temp_table eParent
INNER JOIN
temp_table eChild
ON ( eParent.target = eChild.source )
WHERE eParent.source = <Y>
ORDER BY eParent.weight DESC
LIMIT 20
```

You can try to implement the same logic using Stored Procedures too;